# GWT replacement for java.net.URL

Tags: url, gwt

I have to replace the protocol part of a already existing url in GWT. The `java.net` package has a class which was build for exactly that purpose: [URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URL.html). Sadly GWT [does not emulate the java.net package](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html).

How can I reassemble a url in GWT without creating my own parser? (I know about [UrlBuilder](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/http/client/UrlBuilder.html), but UrlBuilder won't take an existing URL)

Example: I have a url in a string "http://myserver.com/somepath/file.html?param" and I want to replace the protocol part with "https".

Comment: More info needed please. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want the same thing for a different reason. My hash is formatted as a parameter list, and I want to extract / parse out the key/value pairs.  The answer to this is the same answer to my problem.

Answer (score 6):

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    Button btn = new Button("change protocol");
    btn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            UrlBuilder builder = Window.Location.createUrlBuilder().setProtocol("https");
            Window.Location.replace(builder.buildString());
        }
    });
    RootPanel.get().add(btn);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It's ugly, but you can always create an anchor element and extract the parts from there.

```java
AnchorElement a = Document.get().createAnchorElement();
a.setHref("http://test.com/somerandompath");
Window.alert(a.getPropertyString("protocol") + " " + a.getPropertyString("host")) + " " a.getPropertyString("pathname"));

a.removeFromParent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Does [Window.Location](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Location.html) help you at all? You can read out the URL there, mod it and `.assign()` it back.

Comment: No, since Window.Location is not the url I want to modify. And Window.Location won't solve the problem I'm asking about: modifying the url.

Comment: Sheesh, -1 for that?! When the question is so clear. How could I possibly be so silly as to think it was the window location.

Comment: Don't take it personally. Just want to mark it as irrelevant.

Comment: @Martin Algesten: While it might be harsh, I guess that's an appropriate use of the down-vote. @Eduard Wirch: Then you could also just comment on the answer and give the author some time to correct his or her answer (after all they are trying to help), or make it clear - as you did - that they are completely off-base so they can consider deleting their own answer if it is irrelevant.

Comment: Down vote is for things that are completely off topic. `Window.Location` hardly is, and reading the question, how could we possibly know it was? This site is supposed to gather knowledge - imagine someone googles "GWT java.net.URL replacement", my answer may be relevant to that person. Correct it? Well, short of writing the `UrlBuilder` parser that we now understand is actually asked for...

Comment: For what it's worth, this answer is actually exactly what I needed when searching for, well, exactly the functionality Window.Location provides, and not getting any direct hits. So while it's not on-topic for the quesiton, this GWT n00b is glad to have it anyway. :)

Comment: Well, now I'm feeling guilty about it. Sorry Martin, stackoverflow won't let me undo the down vote any more.