# parse query paramaters of a random uri in GWT

Tags: gwt

I am unable to find a reference on how to parse a random uri to access query parameters in GWT. I know `Winodw.Location` allows parsing current window url, but I want to parse another independent url (`Document.get().getReferrer()` in fact).

Any advice on how to proceed is very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get components of the URI, use `com.google.gwt.http.client.UrlBuilder`.

Otherwise, use the "ugly" method described in this Stackoverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9352299/1038832